# Advantages or Disadvantages of Kafka on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-eks

We are exploring the options of having Kafka on AWS EC2 or Kafka on AWS EKS.

What could be the advantage if we use Kafka on EC2 if auto-start up of Kafka related services can be achieved using backend scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You could just ask Amazon Q the same question:

```
 Here are the main advantages and disadvantages of running Kafka on Amazon EKS:

Advantages:

Managed service - With EKS, you don't have to provision and manage the Kubernetes control plane. AWS handles things like patching, upgrades and scaling the control plane.

Integration with other AWS services - EKS makes it easy to use services like Elastic Load Balancing, IAM, VPC, CloudTrail etc. to provide scalability, security and logging for your Kafka applications.

High availability - EKS provides high availability of the control plane across multiple Availability Zones for fault tolerance.

Auto scaling - EKS supports features like horizontal Pod autoscaling and cluster autoscaling to dynamically scale your Kafka clusters based on workload demand.

Disadvantages:

Additional complexity - Running Kafka on EKS adds some complexity compared to a fully managed service like MSK. You need to install and configure Kafka yourself.

Limited configurability - With EKS, you have less control over some Kafka configuration options compared to self-managing Kafka clusters.
```

IMHO the point about the complexity is very important. EKS (K8s itself) has pretty steep learning curve and additional management overhead. Do you have other systems running / deployed on EKS? If yes and you can managed it, then Kafka will be just another component. If not, it may be expensive (time/effort).

As well - you may consider having Amazon MSK if you want managed service too.